# ASP.NET Application to authenticate to Active Directory or SQL via Windows Authentication or Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, sql, active-directory, asp.net-membership, membership

I am in the process of writing an application that will need multiple forms of authentication.

The application will need to support authentication to Active Directory, but be able to fail back to a SQL Membership Provider if the user is not in Active Directory.  We can handle the failing to the SQL Provider in code based on the username provided because the username will be a different format than the Active Directory username.

Is this even possible?  What I mean is, can I use membership and use both ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider and SqlMembershipProvider together or will I have to roll my own?

Another additional added complexity is that I would like to automatically authenticate my internal users based of Windows Authentication back to AD, but use Forms Authentication for users not on our internal network, or users that are using the SQL Provider.

These will most likely be separate servers, one internal, and the other external so I have a lot of planning to do to figure out the data replication, and how I will authenticate the AD users if they hit the outside server etc.

I am wondering what thoughts are out there as I start down this road.  Is what I am wanting to do even possible without me rolling my own, or is there a way to mesh these together?

---

Thanks for the reply.

The reason I asked originally was because I was able to get this specific senerio working about 7 years ago using IIS to authenticate and then passing back the credentials to a Lotus Domino Server Web App.  If the user was not authenticated via the Windows Authentication/ISS then Domino would handle the authentication.  This was what I was looking to do here, but really couldn't think of a way to make it work in IIS.

As for the rest of your reply, I think you are on to the way that I will need to take.  I have thought this through and tossed it around in my head a lot.  The application will be somewhat different on the two servers anyway since there is going to be limited access to the data on the external server anyway.  The fact that so much is going to be different already I may just treat these as two applications, thus negating the need to use two types of authentication in the same application anyway.

I am playing around with the idea already of writing my own authentication/login window for the external server, and if the user trys to log in with their AD credentials on the external server I will be able to detect that and redirect them to the internal server.  If they are not  on the local network or VPN'd in they will simply not get access.  This part still has some thought process to go though so I am not sure.

As an additional thought - is there a way to pull just enough of AD into a SQL database to allow me to authenticate users to the SQL database from the external server using their AD credentials, without creating any security issues?  I hope I am clearly typing what I am thinking....

Thanks again!

Tim

Comment: Since this question and answer are almost 10 years old. I wonder if this solution still works today with IIS 8 and windows 7+?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the way I've handled a similar situation based on [this info](http://beensoft.blogspot.com/2008/06/mixing-forms-and-windows-authentication.html):

1. Configured the application to use Forms authentication.
2. Set the LoginUrl to a page called WinLogin.aspx.
3. In WinLogin.aspx, use Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] to get the username then call FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage( authorizedUserName, false ) to log them in.  I guess you can manually check Active Directory as this point as well.
4. Create an html page that redirects to a page called Login.aspx
5. Login.aspx is your standard username/password login.
6. In IIS, Enable Integrated Authentication and Anonymous on the entire site, but deny anonymous access to WinLogin.aspx.
7. In IIS, set your 401 errors to the page created in step 3.

What basically happens is that when an unauthenicated user hits the site, they're redirected to WinLogin.aspx.  Since anonymous is turned off, integrated security makes a check.  If that passes, your custom code in WinLogin can run.  If the integrated security check fails, a 401 error occurs.  Your custom 401 page redirects to Login.aspx where the user can log in using their username and password with the SQL provider.

Comment: I've used the exact same approach on our main web product. Will not say it's a perfect solution, but the closest thing you can get without rolling something completely new.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Web Applications are configured to use either Windows Authentication or Forms Authentication, but not both.  Therefore, I do not believe it is possible to automatically authenticate internal users while requiring others to enter a username / password.

You could authenticate to Active Directory or a SQL user store via Forms authentication by using a custom provider.  However, the AD users would still need to enter their username and password.  Although I've never combined these two methods, I have used Forms authentication to authenticate against both sources at one time or another.

With that said, I think you may want to consider reducing the "flexibility" of your system.  If you have an external facing server and an internal facing server, you could simply change the provider configuration on each copy of the application to go against a different source.  Then, you could configure the internal one to use Windows (automatic) authentication and the external one to use Forms authentication.

IMHO, I believe that internal users should not be using the external server to access the application.  If they are, they should have a user account stored in SQL, completely separated from their AD account.  Basically, when someone accesses the application externally, they are acting as an external user, irregardless of their physical location.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is possible to use ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider and SqlMembershipProvider, but this requires you design your log on page with your own code instead of the Login controls.

About the mix authentication (Windows and Forms), as far as I know only IIS 7 makes it easy and clean. See this post for details,

http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2008/02/11/IIS-7.0-Two_2D00_Level-Authentication-with-Forms-Authentication-and-Windows-Authentication.aspx